# Variables in a Azure botframework Composer CICD Pipeline

Tags: botframework

*Long time lurker, first-time question so apologies if I do this wrong.*

I have successfully used the following to create a continuous deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps:

[Composer CICD Pipeline Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/composer-samples/csharp_dotnetcore/pipelines/CICDPipelineSample)

However, I would like to use additional pipeline variables to insert into the appsettings.json file: such as additional API keys and the ApplicationInsights connectionString.

Does anyone have experience of doing this or can someone point me in the right direction?

Google has shone no light on this and unfortunately, I have found the botframework documentation to be lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Azure deployments by the pipeline you reference do not use the appsettings.json file. Those settings are ignored.

The pipeline installs pipeline variable values in Azure as App Service Configuration Application Settings using the task "Configure App Service Settings". You might start there.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thank you for taking the time to respond. I had found that task previously however I presumed this was replacing the variables in the appsettings.json file rather than replacing it. I will start there though and see what IO can come up with.